# Writing same object with different value to collection

Tags: java, list, jakarta-ee, arraylist, collections

My question is does an object have to be reinitialized before adding it to a collection with different values ?

I have written a simple program to highlight what I meant.

**Why is the first value(Bravo,1) overwritten in the example below when the line**

`s1 = new student();`

**inside class TestStudent class is commented**

**Student class**

```
public class student {

    String name;
    int id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getName() + " " + this.getId();
    }

}//close student
```

**TestStudent class**

```
public class TestStudent {

public static void main(String args[]){


    student s1 = new student();

    List<student> studlist = new ArrayList<student>();

    s1.setId(1);
    s1.setName("Bravo");

    studlist.add(s1);

    //output is as expected when the below line in uncommented.
    s1 = new student();

    s1.setId(2);
    s1.setName("charlie");

    studlist.add(s1);

    System.out.println( Arrays.toString(studlist.toArray()) );

}//psvm

}//end class
```

**Output with line s1 = new student(); commented**

[charlie 2, charlie 2]

**Output with line s1 = new student(); uncommented**

[Bravo 1, charlie 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it to the collection a second time. However, when you change the values of the object, they are reflected to the output, as the first element of the list refers to the object. List only holds a reference to the object, not a copy of the object.

Answer (score 4):

See, Collections like `List` , `Set` etc just keep references to objects on the heap. So, in your case, both `s1` and `studList's index 0` refer to the same  `Student` instance. Thus changing the object via `s1` will be reflected in the call to `studList.get(0)`. If you do `s1 = new student();`, then `s1` will no longer point to the old `Student` instance. Hence changing it would not affect the list.

Answer (score 1):

The above two answers are good. I find a diagram sometime easier to understand.

The following code:

```
Student s1 = new Student();
students.add(s1);
students.add(s1);

s1 = new Student();
students.add(s1);
```

produces the following data strucutre. Please notice that the firt two items are pointing to the same instance. (Ignore the club.bowling.GameTest package name:))

[image]